# How can i get this type of layout in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-2.0

I have a listbox and it's bound to a list of simple objects. As we know the listbox by default has it's items host as a Stackpanel and so it lays out items in this fashion

```
item1
item2
item3
item4
item5
item6
```

However i have some conditions through which i check whether the item is to be displayed horizontally or vertically and therefore the items could be laid out in this fashion

Eg :-

```
item1
item2
item3 item4 item 5
item6
```

How is it possible to do this?

(If you are wondering why would i ever need such a thing, an example scenario would be "facebook style updates" where if a user uploads 3-4 photos continously they don't always appear on the next line but it may appear horizontally whereas if he posts some event it appears in next line.)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundementals of the solution is to use another `ItemsControl` in the `ItemTemplate` of the `ListBox`.  This `ItemsControl` should have a horizontal oriented `StackPanel` as its `ItemsPanel`.

Here is a basic example.  Lets start with some very simple testdata:-

```
public class TestStringList : List<string>
{
    public TestStringList()
    {
        AddRange(new[] {"Anthony", "Kar", "Martin", "Jon", "Erik", "Darin",
            "Balus", "Mike", "Hans", "Alex", "Anomie", "David" });

    }
}
```

Now we want to display this list in a ListBox but keep all the names that have the same first initial on the same line.  I'm going to use an implementation of `IValueConverter` to deal with the grouping that we need.  If you are using MVVM then you'd have your ViewModel take of this.

```
public class Grouper : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<string>)value).OrderBy(s => s).GroupBy(s => s[0]);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The output of this converter is basically `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` which is what we want.  The outer ListBox will enumerate the outer set and the inner `ItemsControl` will enumerate the inner set of strings which will be a set of names with the same initial.

Here is the xaml:-

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.SimpleGrouping"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:TestStringList x:Key="TestData" />
        <local:Grouper x:Key="grouper" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource grouper}, Source={StaticResource TestData}}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 4):

If using the [MVVM pattern](http://silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/silverlight-4/using-the-mvvm-pattern-in-silverlight-applications/) I would do something like this:

1. Create a ViewModel for the view your list box is in. This VM contains a collection of `ListItemViewModel` instances (see next point)
2. Create a ViewModel called ListItemViewModel (give it a more appropriate name, based on your domain). This view model contains a collection of ItemViewModel instances (see next point).
3. Create a ViewModel called ItemViewModel. Each of these backs a single item in the list. Give this a more appropriate name based on your domain.
4. Create a View that contains your listbox. Bind your listbox to the collection of ListItemViewModels in the VM. The item template for this list box will be a ListItemView (see next point). The items panel template will be the default StackPanel.
5. Create a ListItemView which has a ListItemViewModel data context. This view consists of a horizontal StackPanel of ItemViews (see next point).
6. Create an ItemView which is backed by the ItemViewModel.

Your view would look something like this, each with a correspoding ViewModel.
[image]

Like I said above, you'll definitely want to change the name of your views/view models, mine are for demonstration purposes only :)